# Storing user input in JSON arrays and allowing users to modify them

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am building a simple fitness app as a university exercise. I would like to provide the user with one or two default workout routines  that are structured like this:

```
var workout =
  {
    "title": "Full Body",
    "exercises":
    [
      {
        "name": "Push Ups",
        "duration": 5,
        "break": 5
      },
      {
        "name": "Squats",
        "duration": 5,
        "break": 5
      },
      {
        "name": "Running in place",
        "duration": 5,
        "break": 5
      }
    ]
  };
```

I was thinking that the user might be able to influence a similar array like this:

```
function()
{
  workout.title = document.getElementById(SOME USER INPUT ELEMENT);
  exercises.name = document.getElementById(SOME OTHR USER INPUT ELEMENT);

  etc.
}
```

However I am not sure that this is the most elegant or efficient way to do this. Another thing I would like to do is to allow the user to create their own workout routine: they would input a name (string), choose from a range of exercises (string) and specify the time period (integer) to be assigned to each exercise. This I have no idea how to do and any help would be greatly appreciated!
EDIT: there is no database for this, data is stored locally.

Comment: Please share your `HTML` structure .

Comment: I'm doing a very similar thing and for a mock I used http://jeremydorn.com/json-editor/ with a json schema you can easily create a json object